# How do I test whether a tree has a perfect matching in linear time?

Tags: algorithm, tree

Give a linear-time algorithm to test whether a tree has a perfect matching,
that is, a set of edges that touches each vertext of the tree exactly once.

This is from *Algorithms* by S. Dasgupta, and I just can't seem to nail this problem down. I know I need to use a greedy approach in some manner, but I just can't figure  this out. Help?

Pseudocode is fine; once I have the idea, I can implement in any language trivially.

The algorithm has to be linear in anything. O( V + E ) is fine.

Comment: Could you clarify the problem a bit more? Also, if this is homework, you should tag it as such.  People will still help you.

Comment: It's from a course book, but it's my own post-class exploration of the problem. Not really homework, per say.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think I have the solution. Since we know the graph is a **tree**, we know of the existance of leaf nodes, nodes with one edge and no children. In order for this node to be included in the perfect matching, that edge MUST exist in the final solution.

Ergo, we can find all edges connecting to a leaf node, add to the solution, and remove the touched edges from the graph. If, at the end of this process, we are left any remaining nodes untounched, there exists no perfect matching.

Answer (score 1):

In the case of a "graph", 
The first step of the problem should be to find the connected components.

Since every edge in the final answer connect two vertices, they belong to at most one of the connected components.

Then, the perfect matching could be found for each connected component.

Answer (score 0):

The working algorithm would be something as follows:

```
For each leaf in the tree: 
  add edge from leaf to its parent to the solution
  delete edge from leaf to its parent
  delete all edges from the parent to any other vertices
  delete leaf and parent from the tree

If the tree is empty then the answer is yes. Otherwise, there's no perfect matching.
```

Answer (score -1):

Linear in *what*?  Linear in the number of edges, keep the edges as an ordered incidence list, ie, every edge (*v<sub>i</sub>*, *v<sub>j</sub>*) in some total order.  Then you can compare the two lists in O(*n*) of the edges.

Answer (score -1):

I think that it's a simplified problem of finding a Hamiltonian path in a graph: 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path_problem

I think that there are many solutions on the internet to this problem, but generally finding Hamilton cycle is a NP problem.

Comment: I don't believe the edges have to (or can) be connected in the context of the problem. If each the edges touch each vertex once, the matching cannot contain connected edges. I may be misreading the problem,  however.